# Having trouble decreasing a value in database using JSP

Tags: java, mysql, jsp

I want to be able to update the value by -1 in the stock coloumn.

this is the code i have . this code doesnt seem to be working. the other option in have is to reduce the stock column by what ever number the customers put in the txt box. Would you be able to tell me where am going wrong with this sql statement or how i can implement the second option.

```
<%@ page import="java.sql.ResultSet" %>
<%@ page import="java.sql.SQLException" %>
<%@ page import="java.sql.Statement" %>
<%@ page import="java.sql.Connection" %>
<%@ page import="java.sql.DriverManager" %>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Hello World</title>
</head>
<body>

    <%  
    Connection connect = null;
    Statement s = null;

    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

        connect =  DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/client", "rootroot", "rootroot");

        s = connect.createStatement();

        String strCustomerID = request.getParameter("clientId");
        String strName = request.getParameter("txtName");
        String strEmail = request.getParameter("txtEmail");
        String strStock= request.getParameter("txtStock");
        String strBudget = request.getParameter("txtBudget");





                  String sql = "UPDATE client" +
                               "SET stock = stock - 1" + "WHERE id = '" + strCustomerID + "' ";




                System.out.println(sql);
         s.executeUpdate(sql);;

         out.println("Record Update Successfully");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            out.println(e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            if(s!=null){
                s.close();
                connect.close();
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            out.println(e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    %>

        <li><a href="CustomerView.jsp"> Back to Inventory</a></li>
</body>
</html>
```

What @jan suggested

```
<%@ page import="java.sql.ResultSet" %>
<%@ page import="java.sql.SQLException" %>
<%@ page import="java.sql.Statement" %>
<%@ page import="java.sql.Connection" %>
<%@ page import="java.sql.DriverManager" %>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Hello World</title>
</head>
<body>

    <%  
    Connection connect = null;
    Statement s = null;

    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

        connect =  DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/client", "rootroot", "rootroot");

        s = connect.createStatement();

        String strCustomerID = request.getParameter("clientId");
        String strName = request.getParameter("txtName");
        String strEmail = request.getParameter("txtEmail");
        String strCountryCode = request.getParameter("txtCountryCode");
        String strBudget = request.getParameter("txtBudget");


        //String sql = "DELETE FROM client " + " WHERE id = '" + strCustomerID + "' ";

               // String sql = UPDATE Orders SET Quantity = Quantity + 1 WHERE ...
               // UPDATE client SET stock = stock - 1 WHERE id = 
              //  String sql = "UPDATE client" + "SET stock = stock - 1 "" WHERE id = '" + strCustomerID + "' 



                  String sql = "UPDATE client" +
                               "SET stock = stock - 1 " + " WHERE id = '" + strCustomerID + "'" ; 

        //String sql = "UPDATE client " +
        //      "SET first_name = '"+ strName + "' " +
        //      ", last_name = '"+ strEmail + "' " +
        //      ", blood_type = '"+ strCountryCode + "' " +
        //      ", gender = '"+ strBudget + "' " +

        //      " WHERE id = '" + strCustomerID + "' ";
                System.out.println(sql);
         s.executeUpdate(sql);;

         out.println("Record Update Successfully");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            out.println(e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            if(s!=null){
                s.close();
                connect.close();
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            out.println(e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    %>

        <li><a href="CustomerView.jsp"> Back to Inventory</a></li>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: do `stock = stock - 1` outside of the SQL statement.

Comment: @yogidilip and whats is that supposed to do ?

Comment: @mouneeb what is not working, do you get an exception for example?

Comment: What about checking the return value of  s.executeUpdate(sql) ?

Comment: @QuakeCore I mean to say do the decrement logic outside of the SQL statement and use final value in SQL.

Comment: This is the error that is coming up. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '= stock + 1WHERE id = '7'' at line 1

Comment: What if some evil user tricks the browser into returning "';DROP ALL TABLES;'" as clientId? Better use PreparedStatements.

Comment: @yogidilip can you please give me code example ?

Comment: @GyroGearloose your right  i will use Prepared Statements in the future

Comment: @MuneebKhan are you sure the stock is of type INTEGER  ?

Comment: @GyroGearloose the sql query works fine, is just when i do it this way it doesn't work

Comment: What happens if you try the update statement manually on the database?

Comment: Eeek! I don't know for mySQL, but some databases may wait for a commit. Very frequent error.

Comment: manually works fine.

Comment: @QuakeCore i''ve set that column up as int

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
stock - 1" + "WHERE
```

This will produce `stock -1WHERE` just as your Exception complained. You need an extra space between the -1 and the WHERE in order to have valid SQL. Like this:

```
stock - 1 " + " WHERE
```

Same applies for

```
       client" +
                 "SET
```

should be `client " + "SET`
Apart from that you should consider several changes for better Code quality:

- Use Connection pooling (almost all Servlet Engines hava JNDI support)
- Use PreparedStatement to avoid SQL Injection
- Since Java 7 we have try-with-resource that makes much nicer SQL code (no finally with check for null before close...)

Using PreparedStatement:

```
 PreparedStatement s = null;

 try {
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

    connect =  DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/client", "rootroot", "rootroot");

    s = connect.prepareStatement("UPDATE client SET stock = stock - 1 WHERE id = ?");

    String strCustomerID = request.getParameter("clientId");
    String strName = request.getParameter("txtName");
    String strEmail = request.getParameter("txtEmail");
    String strStock= request.getParameter("txtStock");
    String strBudget = request.getParameter("txtBudget");

    s.setString(1, strCustomerID);
    s.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: hi jan thanks for answering i've tried what you said , but its still giving an error

Comment: Please post error - otherwise there's now way to help you.

Comment: can you suggest how i can do the second option mention

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '= stock - 1 WHERE id = '9'' at line 1

Comment: see my edit - can you post full SQL as given in System.out?

Comment: I've posted the changes  you have suggested

Comment: you still need a blank between SET and stock